# storing images for embedded map application

Tags: c#, compact-framework, filesystems, embedded-database

I have rasterized map in different resolutions, which consists of 15K/60K/240K pictures each sized 256x256, and i have .NET Compact Framework application which can display the map.
But it takes a lot of time to copy 300k files to SD card, approximately 35-60 hours (i copyied just 15K and it took ~ 2 to 2.5 hours), and i'm afraid it will ruin FAT16 filesystem (hardware does not support FAT32, so i can't switch fat16 to fat32) or after copying everything will work very slow.

All pictures are stored like this: /mapdata/res{resolution}/x{x_coord}/y{y_coord}.png

Can any embeddable DB help me? Or should i pack images into zip like /storage/res1/x12.zip with all y*.png archived? Or i just should create ISO-image with all these pictures and just copy iso to SD byte-to-byte?

Comment: What is the total file size of all your images? And are you copying them to the SD card while it's in your device (connected via USB), or are you using a card reader?

Comment: Total size is 1200MB. I tried to copy them using external card reader, internal card-reader (in a laptop), and using the device connected via USB

Comment: even with the slowest available SD card it shouldn't take more than 25 minutes. Maybe it is the large number of small files that are the issue. Try creating a ZIP file and see if that copies quicker.

Comment: @tomlog: yes, number of small files is the issue. and zip file will be copied quickly. that's what my question is about.
and i'm asking, should i use embedded DB, or should i unpack on-the-fly these zip-files.
To show a map i need 4 to 9 files (so at least 2 of them are from different archives) and i everything has be done quickly, say, in 1/10th of a second, and in this 1/10th of second OS should access SD card, find desired folder, find that 2 archive files, open handles, and my software should unpack images from that archives, load them into bitmaps and show everything on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT16 is limited to 65,535 clusters, and a minimum of a single cluster is required per file, which will rule out just using flat files.

I'm assuming your map tiles are to be read-only, so I would take a route of creating a custom file format for your tiles that you control (may also have the added benefit of requiring a bit more effort to take apart, should it fall into the wrong sort of hands).

Maybe something along the lines of:

- Some kind of header, so you know it's your file.
- A tuple which contains the offset from the start of the file to the tile for the "zero" zoom level, and it's length in bytes
- Four tuples for the offsets and lengths for the tiles for zoom level "1"
- ...
- 4^(n) tuples for the offsets and lengths for the tiles at zoom level "n"
- The actual tile data.

It would be relatively lightweight to look up the offsets for a given tile, and override a Stream to do "the right thing" when reporting end of the Stream - you could even use the same offset for "no tile" pictures should you be encoding an area that doesn't fit neatly into a square (like, say, Great Britain)

Comment: this idea has not crossed my mind. looks like a solution. thank you!